What is the difference between using op amp and transistor for small signal amp?
I have a question.
As you know, not only the transistor can be used for switching level or amplifying small signal (single or multiple stage design), but also op-amp can be used in same purpose. So then, what is difference op-amp and transistor for amplifying the small signal?

A typical opamp has a differential input with high impedance, very high voltage gain, and very low output impedance. This is useful for many applications; for voltage amplification specifically it allows precise, repeatable gains that are relatively insensitive to manufacturing tolerances. All these characteristics cannot be achieved simultaneously with a single transistor.

thank you for your comment

You mentioned two (2) applications that are very different; for these two applications, let's compare the pros and cons of using (a) a simple transistor solution (using only 1 or 2 transistors), and (b) an op-amp solution.
Application 1: "switching level" application:
For this application, yes, circuits using single and multiple transistors are often used.  Op-amps, however, are not often used, the main reasons being:
(a) price, and
(b) PCB space.
An op-amp solution will cost more and use more PCB space than a simple 1 or 2-transistor circuit.  Futhermore, a simple transistor solution will be much faster than the op-amp solution for the same component cost; to get the same speed, an op-amp solution will cost many times more than a simple transistor solution.
Application 2:  "amplifying the small signal":
This is a very different application compared to switching, as follows:
a) Input Signal amplitude:
The voltage of the input signal is orders of magnitude lower, typically measured in the mill-volt range, eg: 10mV.  In switching applications, the input signals are typically in the volt range, eg: 3.3V to 5V.
b) Input Signal power:
The input signal can have high internal impedance, which means the input signal can only deliver very low power to the input of the circuit.  For example, an input signal of 10mV with an internal resistance of 10kΩ can deliver at most only 10nW (nano-watts) of power to the input of the amplifier.  For switching applications, the signal source usually has a much larger voltage and lower impedance; for example, in a logic circuit, the voltage can be 5V and the resistance about 50Ω; this can deliver up to 0.5W to the input of the switching circuit, perhaps not continuously but for brief periods.  So when comparing the maximum power capability of the input signal source, the "small signal application" has power levels that is millions or billions of times smaller than the power available in switching applications.
c) Output precision.
When we amplify a small-signal, we want the output to be a larger and very precise copy of the input.  Mathematically, the output voltage of the ideal amplifier is simply the input signal voltage multiplied by a constant factor, which we call "voltage gain", or "Av".  Practically, this degree of precision is very difficult to achieve without using a circuit that uses many transistors, is quite complex, and uses negative feedback - this is exactly what an op-amp is: a circuit that has many transistors, is quite complex, and needs external components to provide the negative feedback.  For switching applications, we don't require the output to be a perfectly scaled version of the input signal, we just want it to be either high or low.

it seems to be different in answers for me about the question. but thank you
